# The trajectory of the particle with E=(0,0,E) and B=(B,0,0)

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to produce the trajectory of the charged particle in $E=(0,0,E)$ and $B=(B,0,0)$. The relevant equations are:
$$y(t) = \frac{E}{\omega B}(\omega t - \sin{\omega t}), \quad z(t) = \frac{E}{\omega B}(1 - \cos{\omega t})$$

This is from Griffiths, D, Introduction to Electrodynamics. I was looking to get a figure looking like this:

[image]

The code that I wrote was

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Velocity = 2.0 10^4;
BField = 100 10^-9;
EField = Velocity*BField;
w = 4;
ParametricPlot3D[{0, EField/(w BField) (w t - Sin[w t]), 
  EField/(w BField) (1 - Cos[w t])}, {t, 0, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Dashed]}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], ViewPoint -> Right, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

This gives a plot which looks like:
[image]

Even though the features are the same, this does not like the one that I am planning to reproduce.

Could anybody let me know, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can also draw the frame manually.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Velocity = 2.0 10^4;
BField = 100 10^-9;
EField = Velocity*BField;
w = 4;
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{0, EField/(w BField) (w t - Sin[w t]), 
     EField/(w BField) (1 - Cos[w t])}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    PlotStyle -> 
     Arrowheads[{{.03, 1/8 + .02}, {.03, 3/8 + .02}, {.03, 
        5/8 + .02}, {.03, 7/8 + .02}}]] /. Line -> Arrow;
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}} = 
  PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange];
frame = Graphics3D[{Black, 
    Arrow[Tube@{1.2 {0, ymin, 0}, 1.2 {0, ymax, 0}}], 
    Arrow[Tube@{{0, 0, 0}, {50000, 0, 0}}], 
    Arrow[Tube@{1.2 {0, 0, zmin}, 2 {0, 0, zmax}}]}];
Show[plot, frame, ViewPoint -> {1, 0.2, .2}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}, 
 Boxed -> {Front, Bottom, Left}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The numerical values for `B` making it hard to visualize since it is so small. How about

```
Velocity = 2.0 10^4;
B0 = 10000;
E0 = Velocity*B0;
w = 4;
z[t_] := E0/(w B0) (1 - Cos[w t])
y[t_] := E0/(w B0) (w*t - Sin[w t])

ParametricPlot3D[{B0, y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 6}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BaseStyle -> 14, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, B0}, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 300, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then use the mouse to change the view point/angle?